# I used import pywhatkit and sendwhatmsg is not working

Tags: python

I used import pywhatkit and sendwhatmsg is not working

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dharshan/Desktop/python_projects/pythonProject/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "C:\Users\dharshan\Desktop\python_projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\__init__.py", line 1
    """This piece of software was last updated on 26-August-2020 at 18:52 IS
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Answer (score 1):

creator of pywhatkit here, consider updating the package using `pip install pywhatkit==3.8`. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MacOS with VS code. Try this code
`python3 -m pip install pywhatkit`